# Getting list of errors (shown in picture) while power on and power off

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, error-handling

[image: screenshot of kernel messages]

What are these errors? Why are they being shown? Is it a start of a bigger problem? Sometimes there is also an error for Bluetooth. What should I do? Do I need to update drivers? How can I use the AMD graphics card?

System details: 7th Gen i5, 4 GB RAM, AMD R5 M430 GPU. The laptop is just one week old.

Comment: Do you have drivers for Radeon videocontroller?

Comment: @RomeoNinov , No , I got Ubuntu 16.04 preinstalled on laptop , I do not know whether AMD cards are supported in ubuntu 16.04.